# Why does while loop in an OMP parallel section fail to terminate when termination condition depends on update from different section

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, openmp

Is the C++ code below legal, or is there a problem with my compiler? The code was complied into a shared library using

gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC)

and openMP and then called via R 2.15.2.

```
int it=0;
#pragma omp parallel sections shared(it)
   {
      #pragma omp section
      {
           std::cout<<"Entering section A"<<std::endl;
           for(it=0;it<10;it++)
           {
                   std::cout<<"Iteration "<<it<<std::endl;

           }
           std::cout<<"Leaving section A with it="<<it<<std::endl;
      }

      #pragma omp section
      {
           std::cout<<"Entering section B with it="<<it<<std::endl;
           while(it<10)
           {
                   1;
           }
           std::cout<<"Leaving section B"<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

I obtain the following output (apologies for interweaving output from 2 threads but I think it is interpretable):

```
Entering section A
Iteration Entering section B with it=0
0
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
Iteration 6
Iteration 7
Iteration 8
Iteration 9
Leaving section A with it=10
```

The program then stalls: section B seems to get stuck in the while loop. Since the variable 'it' is shared I do not understand why the while loop doesn't terminate when section A is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `shared` variable only means it it the same for all threads, but programmer still has to synchronize access by hands

[SHARED Clause](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SHARED)

> It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that multiple threads properly access SHARED variables (such as via CRITICAL sections)

So, you can, for example, [flush](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#FLUSH) variables after first section is completed:

```
      #pragma omp section
      {
           std::cout<<"Entering section A"<<std::endl;
           for(it=0;it<10;it++)
           {
                   std::cout<<"Iteration "<<it<<std::endl;

           }
           #pragma omp flush(it)
           std::cout<<"Leaving section A with it="<<it<<std::endl;
      }

      #pragma omp section
      {
           std::cout<<"Entering section B with it="<<it<<std::endl;
           while(it<10)
           {
            #pragma omp flush(it)
                   1;
           }
           std::cout<<"Leaving section B"<<std::endl;
      }
```

Comment: As a matter of interest is it strictly necessary to add the flush command in section A? Isn't all data copied out of the processor cache into the main memory at the end of a section?